# Do I need bypass diodes when Vout is higher than Vin for an RTC?

Tags: diodes, protection

**I need 3.3 V at all times, but it clashes with a secondary switched on/off 3.3 V I also need. How can I address Vout being higher than Vin, without feeding voltage back into Vin when I don't want it there?**

I'm working on a project that is battery powered with two 18650's.  It requires an RTC that is built into the uController I am using (Sparkfun's Artemis).
This means I need to always supply 3.3 V to the Artemis.
So I have my "switched on/off" portion of the circuit, battery -> load switch -> 5 V reg. -> 3.3 V reg.

It's probably important to also note that there are other powered components after the load switch, beyond the 5 V & 3.3 V regulators.

Then I have an extra low power 3.3 V regulator that is not switched, for the RTC...   so, battery -> 3.3 V (The Artemis can deep sleep on the order of 10's of uAmps)
This means that when I want the system to be powered "off", the uController will always have 3.3 V in it because the uController needs power for its RTC, even if minimal.
Does it make sense to do something like in the following picture, to the 3.3 V regulator on the switched rail?

[image: reverse current protection]

I could do this instead,

[image: bypass diode]

but then 3.3 V will exist in my "switched on/off" power rail, when off, which doesn't sound ideal because of a few other IC's that may be in a brown state because of that (I.E. a high voltage power controller)

**What is a good way to tackle this design challenge?**

Small note..  I do have battery protection circuitry, so if the battery voltage falls below 6 volts, a high-side MOSFET will shutoff, at which point I don't mind losing power to the RTC.  My load switch shuts off power when it gets near this threshold, but just not to the low power 3.3 V regulator.

---

Upon further investigation, I think the key term I was looking for is "reverse current & reverse voltage protection" in my parts search.  I didn't realize this was a feature for some power regulators, an example being the [TL1963A-33DCQT](https://www.ti.com/store/ti/en/p/product/?p=TL1963A-33DCQT)

Comment: You do probably have a separate Vbat for RTC. Then you put a coin cell battery like every embedded board that needs RTC has.

Comment: That would be awesome, but I don't think there is one for this one.. 
 https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/9/0/9/Apollo3_Pad_Mapping.pdf